# angular views not loading

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-routing

I am a noob to node and angular and am trying to build and app with a few pages. I have followed tutorials to the exact point and for whatever reason, my application is not working and will not load my views. It renders the index.html page just fine, but when i goto one of the other URL's it is not displaying my views into the ng-view div. Any help is appreciated

Here is what my console looks like at the login Url
[image]

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var routes = require("./api/index");

//Controllers//
var positionController = require('./api/controllers/position');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'api')));
app.use('/api', routes);


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});

var port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port: '+ port)
  });

  module.exports = app;
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>ITSC</title>

      <script src="./angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="./angular/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="./app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <a href="#/login">login</a>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <script src="./controllers/position.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

login.html

```
<div class="container login">
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email@website.com" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                <button type="submit">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateURL:'partials/apply.html'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        templateURL:'partials/login.html'
    })
    .when('/managers',{
        templateURL:'partials/managers.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'partials/apply.html'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: It's `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: wow. I cannot believe that I didn't catch this. Thank you, combine this with the accepted answer and my problem is completely solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare some Controllers, for example:

```
.when('/',{
  templateURL:'partials/apply.html',
  controller: 'ApplyController'
})

angular.module('myApp').controller('ApplyController',function(){
  ...
})
```